# How to add semicolon to the end of accessor declaration

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have built `AccessorDeclarationSyntax` instance that contains expression body based accessor.

It looks like:

```
get => myField
```

And it is without semicolon.

How can I add semicolon after `myField` in `AccessorDeclarationSyntax` instance?

Comment: What is it you are trying to do?  Write a c# parser?

Comment: I am working on C# code analyzer (+ code fixer capabilities). I have converted property block body to the expression body, but there are no semicolons after get and set accessors. And I would like to understand, how can I add semicolon  to the end of `AccessorDeclarationSyntax` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RoslynQuoter](https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/) says:

```
AccessorDeclaration(
    SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration)
.WithExpressionBody(
    ArrowExpressionClause(
        LiteralExpression(
            SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression,
            Literal(2))))
.WithSemicolonToken(
    Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken))
```